# GridDB Question: Is the Java Client thread safe?

Tags: java, database, iot, griddb

I'm developing a GridDB application that uses multithreading and am experiencing random exceptions and deadlocks. Is the Java client thread safe?

And for those curious, here is the GridDB product page: https://griddb.net

Comment: Link to the GridDB project or product web site or wikipedia for background info.

Answer (score 0):

Are you using the same GridStore instance for multiple threads?
A single Gridstore instance is not thread safe. Please refer to the following:

http://griddb.org/griddb_nosql/manual/GridDB_API_Reference.html#GridStoreFactory.html__
"... since thread safety is not guaranteed for GridStore itself, it is not allowed to call a method of a single GridStore instance from two or more threads at an arbitrary time."